# path segment conflicts with existing wildcard in path

Tags: go, go-gin

I want to rewrite flask application in golang-gin, and i have a path problem in routes, :status have only 3 version `start` `pause` `end` , this is my current routes :

```
    contracts.POST("/:id/:status", s.contractChangeStatus)
    contracts.POST("/:id/events/:type", AccessRole(models.Work), s.eventCreate)
```

problem is when i execute app, return this error :

```
panic: path segment 'events/:type' conflicts with existing wildcard ':status' in path '/contracts/:id/events/:type'
```

what is the best practice for solve this situation ? in flask exist a simple path /any(start|pause|stop), how i can solve this in golang-gin ? without change api structure !

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/205.  Gin-gonic has had this problem for a while, and there appears to be workarounds.

Comment: Also, take a look at the answers for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845807/gin-wildcard-route-conflicts-with-existing-children?rq=1